# $ObjectType and picklistValues attribute

Tags: visualforce, describesobject, describefieldresult

I've tried to use

```
{!$ObjectType.Case.fields.Status.picklistValues}
```

but it doesn't work

```
Error: Unsupported type common.api.soap.wsdl.PicklistEntry encountered.
```

Based on the documentation I see that it is possible to refer to picklistValues:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_objecttype_schema_fields_reference.htm

Comment: I was never able to get this working either :( a tad unfortunate, as one has to break out an Apex controller in order to get at or assemble picklist values into a list.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we are getting same problem.

Your problem is related to this post.
[How can I get picklist values using Dynamic Visualforce Bindings?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8259/how-can-i-get-picklist-values-using-dynamic-visualforce-bindings)